# OpenCV Image stiching when camera parameters are known

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

We have pictures taken from a plane flying over an area with 50% overlap and is using the OpenCV stitching algorithm to stitch them together. This works fine for our version 1. In our next iteration we want to look into a few extra things that I could use a few comments on.

Currently the stitching algorithm estimates the camera parameters. We do have camera parameters and a lot of information available from the plane about camera angle, position (GPS) etc. Would we be able to benefit anything from this information in contrast to just let the algorithm estimate everything based on matched feature points?

These images are taken in high resolution and the algorithm takes up quite amount of RAM at this point, not a big problem as we just spin large machines up in the cloud. But I would like  to in our next iteration to get out the homography from down sampled images and apply it to the large images later. This will also give us more options to manipulate and visualize other information on the original images and be able to go back and forward between original and stitched images.

If we in question 1 is going to take apart the stitching algorithm to put in the known information, is it just using the `findHomography` method to get the info or is there better alternatives to create the homography when we actually know the plane position and angles and the camera parameters.

I got a basic understanding of opencv and is fine with c++ programming so its not a problem to write our own customized stitcher, but the theory is a bit rusty here.

Comment: What resolution are you capturing the images in? If they are sufficiently high, then you could downsample them but I'd advise you to avoid it as much as possible (I am not a big fan of downsampling). You can do the stichting using either the feature points OR a calibrated camera (I am not sure if a combination would be a viable solution); you could use the camera parameters to quicken your homography function, though.

Comment: 5000x7400 pixels (50mb) raw files. At this time I am wondering if it makes sense to spend time on getting knowledge about using the camera parameters for anything or matching features is fine as long as it works. But thanks for your comment. But there should not really be anything wrong with down sampling the images. down sampling also removes some noise from the image I would assume.

Comment: Is your GPS information accurate enough for fine adjustment of the images?

Comment: I have not tried that yet, but thinking about it its most likely not and the answers also indicate that one would use image features also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using homographies to warp your imagery, I assume you are capturing areas small enough that you don't have to worry about Earth curvature effects. Also, I assume you don't use an elevation model.

Generally speaking, you will always want to tighten your (homography) model using matched image points, since your final output is a stitched image. If you have the RAM and CPU budget, you could refine your linear model using a max likelihood estimator.

Having a prior motion model (e.g. from GPS + IMU) could be used to initialize the feature search and match. With a good enough initial estimation of the feature apparent motion, you could dispense with expensive feature descriptor computation and storage, and just go with normalized crosscorrelation.

Comment: Thanks, these comments are good. Its the conclusion I am at now also that I can use the prior information to simplify the areas of searching features and speed up the process this way. Glad to know that I always would want to tighten the homography with matched image points. At this point we are typical stiching 5-15 images together to cover local area. But I am also very interested in where to look for information if we was to stitch things together to a bug image also having the earth curvatures included and presenting a large map over a large area.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, the images are taken vertically and overlap by a known amount of pixels, in that case calculating homography is a bit overkill: you're just talking about a translation matrix, and using more powerful algorithms can only give you bad conditioned matrixes.

In 2D, if H is a generalised homography matrix representing a perspective transformation,

```
H=[[a1 a2 a3] [a4 a5 a6] [a7 a8 a9]]
```

then the submatrixes R and T represent rotation and translation, respectively, if a9==1.

```
R= [[a1 a2] [a4 a5]], T=[[a3] [a6]]
```

while `[a7 a8]` represents the stretching of each axis. (All of this is a *bit* approximate since when all effects are present they'll influence each other).

So, if you known the lateral displacement, you can create a 3x3 matrix having just `a3`, `a6` and `a9=1` and pass it to `cv::warpPerspective` or `cv::warpAffine`.

As a criteria of matching correctness you can, f.e., calculate a normalized diff between pixels.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. I think Francesco has a point that using the image points to tighten the homography is always a good idea.

Comment: That's true, but be careful with the homography estimation using RANSAC and groups of four points because it can give badly conditioned matrices. A possibility is to use feature correspondent homography calculation, extract the matrix T and verify that R and the stretching submatrixes are not going bananas.

Comment: Just to confirm, you are saying to verify that the RANSAC found homography should be verified from the know information we have from gps and flight data ?

Comment: Yes. RANSAC algorithm is robust to noise, but how much, depends on the possible amount of iterations, i.e. how many chances it gets to pick four correspondences, calculate their H matrix and verify this H with all the other point correspondences (basically, four `for` nested loops :S). Plus, the output accuracy "floor" depends on the "sharpness" of the input images (f.e. atmosphere, Point Spread Function of the sensor/camera).